# php - initialize array keys and insert values

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to create an array like a "table" with my headers as my keys, say name, age address.

I want to initialize my keys and insert new values (Imagine an SQL table). Is there a nicer way to do this?

```
$table = array();

foreach($rows as $key => $row){
 array_push($table, array());
 $table[$key]['name'] = $row['name'];
 $table[$key]['age'] = $row['age'];
 $table[$key]['address'] = $row['address'];
 if($row['age'] >= 18) $table[$key][$val_1] = 1;
 else $table[$key][$val_2] = 1;
}
```

And imagine there are val_1 ,..., val_n and I can initialize them as 0 from the start.

Comment: My bad. There shouldn't be a $ sign.

Comment: and `$rows` are a result of a query call?

Comment: @vlzvl: +1 I was going to ask same because nowhere $row is defined or initialized !

Comment: Yes. It is a result of a query call

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = array();

foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    if ($row['age'] >= 18) {
        $row[$val_1] = 1;
    } else {
        $row[$val_2] = 1;
    }

    $table[$key] = $row;
}
```

That's assuming `$row` contains only the keys you want anyway. If this is coming from an SQL query, `SELECT` only the columns you want. If you do need to trim it down to a specific selection of keys, do this before:

```
$row = array_intersect_key($row, array_flip(array('name', 'age', 'address')));
```

If `$key` is just a numeric key, leave it out and just do `$table[] = $row`.

The `$val_1`/`$val_2` seems like bad design, but it's impossible to suggest any improvement without knowing what it's for.